# Error en cálculo con valores decimales

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que elimine el IVA de un precio, tiene 2 funcionalidades, si el IVA es con decimales o es entero. La parte que saca el IVA entero funciona correctamente, pero la parte que saca el IVA en decimales no. Intenté modificando el cálculo pero no funcionó, este es el código (el de los decimales es el primero):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int multi, rt;
    float ivaA, precioA, finalA, ivaB, precioB, finalB, divi;


    cout<<"\nSu iva contiene decimales?";
    cout<<"\n\n1- Si";
    cout<<"\n2- No";
    cout<<"\n\nIntroduzca su respuesta, por favor: ";
    cin>>rt;

    if (rt==1){

        cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del IVA, por favor: ";cin>>ivaA;
        cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del producto, por favor: ";cin>>precioA;

        multi = precioA * ((ivaA/100+1)-1) ;

        finalA = precioA - multi;

        cout<<"\nEl total de su producto sin IVA es: ";cout<<finalA;
        cout<<"\nEl valor del IVA eliminado es: ";cout<<multi;

    }

    else{

        cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del IVA, por favor: ";cin>>ivaB;
        cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del producto, por favor: ";cin>>precioB;

        divi = (precioB / (1+(ivaB/100)));

        finalB = precioB - divi;

        cout<<"\nEl total de su producto sin IVA es: ";cout<<divi;
        cout<<"\nEl valor del IVA eliminado es: ";cout<<finalB;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Creo que sería bueno que pusieras ejemplos de funcionamiento en dónde especifiques datos de entrada, los resultados que arroja el actual programa (erróneos) y los resultados deseados que esperarías obtener. De esta manera, se la comunidad podría tener una mejor idea del funcionamiento esperado.

Comment: Una pregunta ¿por qué cambias la fórmula con respecto a la usada con enteros? Supongo que "con decimales" se refiere a que se ingresa 21.5 y no 21 simplemente, es decir, sigue siendo en tanto por ciento ¿no? ¿O es que se ingresa 0.21?

Comment: Hola! cambie la fórmula porque lo intenté con la que usé en los enteros pero no me funcionó, los valores que estuve usando fueron:
IVA: 10.5
PRECIO: 110.5

Comment: A todos los que comentaron, muchas gracias! Ya lo pude resolver, tengo un problema al leer y por eso no entendí bien sus respuestas, ahora las acabo de re leer detenidamente y tenía invertidos los couts. Muchas gracias nuevamente y buenas tardes! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a hacerlo con esta fórmula, lo he probado y me ha funcionado:

```
if (rt==1){

    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del IVA, por favor: ";cin>>ivaA;
    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del producto, por favor: ";cin>>precioA;

    divi = precioA / (1+(ivaA/100)) ;

    finalA = precioA - divi;

    cout<<"\nEl total de su producto sin IVA es: ";cout<<divi;
    cout<<"\nEl valor del IVA eliminado es: ";cout<<finalA;

}
```

[La fórmula la he tomado de aquí](https://www.scoosh.com/vat-calculator/)

Comment: Hola! La que no funciona es la de multi, la de divi funciona perfectamente para numeros enteros.

Comment: Hola, sí lo sé. Es solo que le cambié el nombre a 'multi' por 'divi' porque la fórmula que uso es una división. Fíjate que en el if está la condición de rt==1. Prueba a sustituirla en tu código a ver si te funciona :)

Comment: Hola! Sip, lo acabo de probar y me dio bien ya, muchas gracias a todos los que comentaron!

Answer (score 0):

#include

using namespace std;

int main(){

```
int multi, rt;
float ivaA, precioA, finalA, ivaB, precioB, finalB, divi;


cout<<"\nSu iva contiene decimales?";
cout<<"\n\n1- Si";
cout<<"\n2- No";
cout<<"\n\nIntroduzca su respuesta, por favor: ";
cin>>rt;

if (rt==1){

    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del IVA, por favor: ";cin>>ivaA;
    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del producto, por favor: ";cin>>precioA;

    multi = precioA * ((ivaA/100+1)-1) ;

    finalA = precioA - multi;

    cout<<"\nEl total de su producto sin IVA es: ";cout<<finalA;
    cout<<"\nEl valor del IVA eliminado es: ";cout<<multi;

}

else{

    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del IVA, por favor: ";cin>>ivaB;
    cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor del producto, por favor: ";cin>>precioB;

    divi = (precioB / (1+(ivaB/100)));

    finalB = precioB - divi;

    cout<<"\nEl total de su producto sin IVA es: ";cout<<divi;
    cout<<"\nEl valor del IVA eliminado es: ";cout<<finalB;

}

return 0;
```

}

Regard: [vat](https://vatcalculatorg.com/)

Comment: Bienvenido. Las respuestas que son solo código no son bien recibidas.